Apex charts for vue js enable tooltip for legend series
In Apex pie charts I need to enable the default tooltip while hovering the legend how to do that.
            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                    width: 380,
                    type: 'pie',
                },
                labels: ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team D', 'Team E'],
                responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    options: {
                        chart: {
                            width: 200
                        },
                    }
                }],
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    onItemClick: {
                        toggleDataSeries: true
                    },
                    onItemHover: {
                        highlightDataSeries: true,
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
            },

I need to enable the default tooltip while hovering the legend

I can't find it in the docs, and an issue from 4 years ago at least referenced it as having no plans to be implemented: https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/772

Apparently Apexcharts doesn't provide it. But you can find a workaround for this here: How to show legend tooltip when hover on legend series in ApexCharts.js
